# Планировщик заданий не сохраняет excel файл

Tags: python, планировщик-задач

Добрый день! Помогите разобраться с данной проблемой.

Написал скрипт на питоне, который берет данные из базы и записывает в эксель.
Если использую планировщик заданий, то все успешно выполняется, но файла excel я нигде не вижу, который должен быть на выходе.
Делаю вручную через консоль, файл создается, все как нужно мне.

Почему планировщик заданий не сохраняет excel файл?

Comment: Совершенно верно, не обязательный, и в его отсутствии используется текущая директория. Проблема в том, что текущии директории при ручном запуске и из планировщика разные. Но и это решаемо, планировщик позволяет указать директорию, из которой будет запускаться скрипт, это и будет рабочая директория скрипта. По всей видимости, вы это поле оставили пустым.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, помог последний [ответ отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820368/python-task-scheduler-0%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bx1).
Моя проблема была в том, что я не указывал рабочую папку. Хотя там указано, что это необязательный пункт.

- Программа/скрипт: C:\Python27\python.exe (Полный путь исполняемого файла)
- Добавить аргументы (если требуется): test.py (Имя файла, который будет запускаться)
- Рабочая папка (если требуется): C:\Python27  (Полный путь к папке, где лежит файл)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/128924)

Comment: @Denis спасибо большое. :)